# AWS Elastic Beanstalk/Django: How do I get static files to work?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running the newest Django/Python version on Elastic Beanstalk, which I believe runs on Amazon Linux 2023.

My Django website is finally deployed (after much blood, sweat and tears). My website correctly displays all HTML/Database info, but it's missing CSS/JS, which are contained within the static files.

Some of the elastic beanstalk documentation is a bit deprecated - I tried following [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-cfg-staticfiles.html):
But my configuration contained absolutely no mentions of static files at all.

What am I missing, and how can I add them?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your AWS Elastic Beanstalk configuration ? And eventually any webserver configuration and any other files in your .platform folder if you have ?